# Iterator validity following a std::move of pointed element

Tags: c++, iterator, move-semantics

I wasn't able to find anything in the standard regarding this, is this UB or well defined behaviour?

```cpp
// Assuming T supports move semantics
void sink(T&& t) 
{
    // bla bla
}

std::list<T> list = getSomeList();

for (auto it = list.begin(); it != list.end(); )
{
    if (some pred) 
    {
        sink(std::move(*it));
        it = list.erase(it) // is this valid following the std::move() ??
    }
    else
        ++it;
}
```

Comment: Yes it's valid, why not ? `std::move()` does not move anything. The object still exists but may be at worst in an indeterminate state, but it's still there (in the list in this case) and still removable/destructible by the way.

Comment: It should be valid. From the standard : *Unless otherwise specified, such moved-from objects shall be placed in a valid but unspecified state.* So the iterator still refers to a valid object (only its internal state should no longer be used)

Comment: Whether or not the item the iterator points to is moved (and if moved, that object is itself still valid), the **iterator** itself is still valid.  Also, you've done the right thing handling the iteration correctly in both arms of the if/else — that's often a stumbling block.

Comment: Not only this is a valid code, this is a commonly used pattern.

Comment: Yes, this (or something every similar) is pretty much the only way to move data out of a container.

Comment: @user1806566 list in particular happens to have another way, for moving elements to another list specifically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moving from - or more generally: making any changes to - a pointed element has no effect on the iterator. It will remain valid.

P.S. your example doesn't actually move from the element. It only binds an rvalue reference to it.

Comment: Yeah of course, in the real code `sink` wi consume T, my question was about the the iterator validity. Thanks!